# VS Code SFDX Salesforce CLI Deployment issue

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli

From VS Code when trying to run below command

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest c:\temp_worspace\temp-folder\manifest\package.xml --json --loglevel fatal
```

Getting below error

> UnexpectedFileFound: Unexpected file found in package directory:
>   c:\temp_worspace\temp-folder\force-app\main\default\documents\temp-meta.xml

Same error is occurred while running the retrieve command.

Checked the `.forceignore` file as well.

Comment: Seems like you have some unwanted files in the source folder, need to remove those, then try.

Comment: But the same source i am able to deploy through ant its the only issue with sfdx cli deployment.

Comment: Ant doesn't deploy Salesforce DX format source - there must be a conversion pass that removes this unnecessary file.